# Kubectl get file creation time in pod

Tags: python, kubernetes

How can I get time created of file (epoch) inside pod using `kubectl exec` or `Kubernetes API for python`?

I need this time to calculate the time elapsed from now to file created time.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a `kubeconfig` file under `~/.kube/config`

```
from kubernetes import client, config
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint

config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()

namespace = 'default'

try:
    api_response = v1.list_namespaced_pod(namespace)
    pprint(api_response.items[0].metadata.creation_timestamp)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling CoreV1Api->list_namespaced_pod: %s\n" % e)
```

It returns tzutc, which you will need to parse.

```
$ python3 get_pods.py
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 25, 16, 2, 39, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer but my question is how to get the creation time of file inside the pod and NOT the pod creation time

Comment: you mean if you do `touch file` inside the pod, and through python, to get that info?

Comment: exactly, I need to know the create time of this file